# Custom search output of SharePoint online is not returning consistent data

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

To implement the search across the site collections in the SharePoint online, we have implemented following step:
In Content Type hub site collection:

1. Create site column named AA  in the content type hub
2. Create site content type named BB (based content type is document) and attached above created site column AA with this.
3. Publish the content type BB

In admin site collection

- Create the manage property named CC in the search schema of the tenant admin

In new created site collection named DD

1. Add the site content type BB with newly created library named FF
2. Upload the document with parameter AA.

Currently we are facing below inconsistency issues:

1. All the documents having the same value of AA column are not returning, missed few documents when search in the search box of site collection by CC:222.
2. Sometime we are not getting values when search in the search box of other site collection by CC:222.

Comment: In all the sites using this content type, did you request a site reindex after making the configuration changes? Site Settings -> Search and offline availability-> reindex site?

Comment: Yes, I have done all these activities. Even from library setting I have done re indexing..But nothing happened

Comment: For your information all of the managed property detail:
type: Text  
Main characteristics: searchable is checked  
Querable: Querable is checked  
Retrievable:  Rerievable is checked  
Token Normalization : Token normalization is checked  
Mapping to crawled properties: ows_BB,ows_q_text_BB